# Writing a graphing program using methods

Tags: java, function, methods, graph

I am writing a java program that graphs linear and quadratic functions. So far, all I've done is made the axes where the functions will be graphed on in the main. Here is my code:

```
    int yMax = 5;
    int yMin = -5;
    int xMax = 5;
    int xMin = -5;


    for(int j=yMax; j>=yMin; j--)
    {
        for(int i=xMin; i<=xMax; i++)
        {
            if(j==5 && i==0)
            {
                System.out.print("^");
            }
            else if(i==5 && j==0)
            {
                System.out.print(">");
            }
            else if(i==0 & j==0)
            {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            else if(j==0)
            {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            else if(i==0)
            {
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    System.out.println();   
    }
```

The code works fine, the axes are drawn perfectly. The only thing is that I need to do this using a method that takes in two int values (i and j) and returns a string (the character to be drawn), and thats what I dont know how to do. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to String value as a return of method

Comment: I believe you have a typo in the `i==0 & j==0` case; it should be `&&` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int yMax = 5;
        int yMin = -5;
        int xMax = 5;
        int xMin = -5;
        String result = ""; // returns string (character to be drawn)
        for (int j = yMax; j >= yMin; j--) {
            for (int i = xMin; i <= xMax; i++) {
                if (j == 5 && i == 0) {
                    result += "^";
                } else if (i == 5 && j == 0) {
                    result += ">";
                } else if (i == 0 & j == 0) {
                    result += ".";
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    result += "-";
                } else if (i == 0) {
                    result += "|";
                } else {
                    result += " ";
                }
            }
            result += "\n";
        }
```

Comment: OP asked for _"a method that takes in two int values (i and j) and returns a string (the character to be drawn)"_. This doesn't do anything like that. The return value will not be a character, but rather a `String` representation of the axes in their entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Just capture your logic in a method and replace the `System.out.println()` calls with `return` statements. Since a `return` statement stops execution of the method, you can drop the `else` branches:

```
public String getCharacter(int i, int j) {
    if(j==5 && i==0) return "^";
    if(i==5 && j==0) return ">";
    if(i==0 && j==0) return ".";
    if(j==0) return "-";
    if(i==0) return "|";
    return " ";
}
```

Your main program would then be:

```
int yMax = 5;
int yMin = -5;
int xMax = 5;
int xMin = -5;


for(int j=yMax; j>=yMin; j--)
{
    for(int i=xMin; i<=xMax; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(getCharacter(i, j));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The above can also be done as a nested ternary operator:

```
public String getCharacter(int i, int j) {
    return j==5 && i==0 ? "^"
         : i==5 && j==0 ? ">"
         : i==0 && j==0 ? "."
         : j==0         ? "-"
         : i==0         ? "|"
         :                " ";
}
```

Unfortunately, most Java formatters won't preserve that nice layout and would render the statement an unintelligible mess.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but the thing is I'm not sure how to call it in the main.